# Explanation needed for Arduino code

Tags: arduino, sensors

Just came across a code for converting analog readings from force sensor to force in newtons. I'm not sure how its done. Hope someone can explain it to me. Thanks! I found the codes here http://learn.adafruit.com/force-sensitive-resistor-fsr/using-an-fsr

```
if (fsrVoltage == 0) {
    Serial.println("No pressure");  
} else {
    // The voltage = Vcc * R / (R + FSR) where R = 10K and Vcc = 5V
    // so FSR = ((Vcc - V) * R) / V        yay math!
    fsrResistance = 5000 - fsrVoltage;     // fsrVoltage is in millivolts so 5V = 5000mV
    fsrResistance *= 10000;                // 10K resistor
    fsrResistance /= fsrVoltage;
    Serial.print("FSR resistance in ohms = ");
    Serial.println(fsrResistance);

    fsrConductance = 1000000;           // we measure in micromhos so 
    fsrConductance /= fsrResistance;
    Serial.print("Conductance in microMhos: ");
    Serial.println(fsrConductance);

    // Use the two FSR guide graphs to approximate the force
    if (fsrConductance <= 1000) {
        fsrForce = fsrConductance / 80;
        Serial.print("Force in Newtons: ");
        Serial.println(fsrForce);      
    } else {
        fsrForce = fsrConductance - 1000;
        fsrForce /= 30;
        Serial.print("Force in Newtons: ");
        Serial.println(fsrForce);            
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't you understand? Code or math?

Comment: it is a structured code with comments, what is it you don't understand?

Comment: I don't understand the math behind the codings. How did they get from conductance to force in newtons?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at pg6 of this document  http://www.imagesco.com/sensors/fsr/fsrguide.pdf 
There are two graphs, one for heavy weights and one for lighter ones. If you run linear regression on them and convert the units, you should get the two equations in the code.